# PHP statment not working on an include

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a PHP statement on a sidebar, the sidebar is included on all pages.
In the sidebar I want hide content on the results page, so I'm using this:

```
<?php
if ($page!='results')
{?>
<h1>THE MAIN SIDEBAR CONTENT</h1>
<div>
SOME CONTENT          
</div>
<?php }  ?>
```

The problem is that it looks like its not recognising the page as having

```
$page='results';
```

at the top of it. Maybe because the code is in a included page but I thought it would just get read as one page?

If I add

```
$page='results';
```

to the start of the above script, it works (just to verify I have written the code correctly.

I have also checked that results.php has

```
$page='results';
```

right at the very top of it.

Can I not use this code on an include or am I missing something?

As per navnav's request, here is the code for the include and the actual page. NOTE I am not actually using '$results' I'd just used that as an example for my post. In the real code below, you'll see I am using '$getvaluation'

**Code for sidebar....**

```
<div class="right_part right_home">
      <h1 style="padding-left: 25px">Property <span>Search</span></h1>

      <script type="text/javascript">
          $('#couHertfordshire').click(function(){
            var v = $(this).val();
            $('#couHertfordshire_hide').val(v);
          });
           $('#couLondonNorth').click(function(){
            var v = $(this).val();
            $('#couLondonNorth_hide').val(v);
          });
           $('#couLondonNorthWest').click(function(){
            var v = $(this).val();
            $('#couLondonNorthWest_hide').val(v);
          });
      </script>

      <?php
            $page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            $page = explode('/', $page);
        if (isset($_POST['bed']) && $_POST['bed'] != '' && $page[2] == 'test.php'){
            $url = 'http://www.vebra.com/home/quick/PFrefine.asp';
            $target = 'target="hello"';
            $js_submit = true;                  

            $bed = $_POST['bed'];
            $min = $_POST['lop'];
            $max = $_POST['hip'];
            $area1 = $_POST['cou1'];
            $area2 = $_POST['cou2'];
            $area3 = $_POST['cou3'];
            // Hidden Fields
            $hidden1 = $_POST['slo'];
            $hidden2 = $_POST['fid'];
            $hidden3 = $_POST['bid'];
            $hidden4 = $_POST['dbt'];
            $hidden5 = $_POST['nre'];
            $hidden6 = $_POST['thu'];
            $hidden7 = $_POST['vto'];
            $hidden8 = $_POST['ord'];
            $hidden9 = $_POST['nba'];

        } else {

            $url = 'test.php';
            $target = '';
            $js_submit = false;
        }           

      ?>

      <form method="post" action="<?php echo $url; ?>" name="searchform" id="searchform" <?php echo $target; ?> >
        <dl id="property_search">
          <dt class="bord">Bedrooms</dt>
          <dd><select name="bed" class="type1 Selectrooms">
                  <option <?php if($bed == '0'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="0">0</option>
                  <option <?php if($bed == '1'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="1">1</option>
                  <option <?php if($bed == '2'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="2">2</option>
                  <option <?php if($bed == '3'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="3">3</option>
                  <option <?php if($bed == '4'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="4">4</option>
                  <option <?php if($bed == '5'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="5">5+</option>
              </select>
          </dd>

          <dt class="bord">Minimum Price</dt>
          <dd><select class="type2 SelectPrices" name="lop">
                <option <?php if ($min == '0'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="0">&#163;0</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '25000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="25000">&#163;25,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '50000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="50000">&#163;50,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '75000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="75000">&#163;75,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '100000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="100000">&#163;100,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '125000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="125000">&#163;125,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '150000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="150000">&#163;150,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '175000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="175000">&#163;175,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '200000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="200000">&#163;200,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '225000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="225000">&#163;225,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '250000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="250000">&#163;250,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '275000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="275000">&#163;275,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '300000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="300000">&#163;300,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '325000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="325000">&#163;325,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '350000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="350000">&#163;350,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '375000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="375000">&#163;375,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '400000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="400000">&#163;400,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '500000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="500000">&#163;500,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '600000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="600000">&#163;600,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '700000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="700000">&#163;700,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '800000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="800000">&#163;800,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '900000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="900000">&#163;900,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '1000000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="1000000">&#163;1,000,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '2000000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="2000000">&#163;2,000,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '3000000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="3000000">&#163;3,000,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '4000000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="4000000">&#163;4,000,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '5000000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="5000000">&#163;5,000,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($min == '6000000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="6000000">&#163;6,000,000</option>
              </select>
          </dd>

          <dt class="bord">Maximum Price</dt>
          <dd><select name="hip" class="type3 SelectPrices">
                <option <?php if ($max == '25000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="25000"> &#163;25,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($max == '50000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="50000">&#163;50,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($max == '75000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="75000">&#163;75,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($max == '100000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="100000">&#163;100,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($max == '125000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="125000">&#163;125,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($max == '150000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="150000">&#163;150,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($max == '175000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="175000">&#163;175,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($max == '200000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="200000">&#163;200,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($max == '225000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="225000">&#163;225,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($max == '250000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="250000">&#163;250,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($max == '275000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="275000">&#163;275,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($max == '300000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="300000">&#163;300,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($max == '325000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="325000">&#163;325,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($max == '350000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="350000">&#163;350,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($max == '375000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="375000">&#163;375,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($max == '400000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="400000">&#163;400,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($max == '500000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="500000">&#163;500,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($max == '600000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="600000">&#163;600,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($max == '700000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="700000">&#163;700,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($max == '800000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="800000">&#163;800,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($max == '900000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="900000">&#163;900,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($max == '1000000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="1000000">&#163;1,000,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($max == '2000000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="2000000">&#163;2,000,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($max == '3000000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="3000000">&#163;3,000,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($max == '4000000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="4000000">&#163;4,000,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($max == '5000000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="5000000">&#163;5,000,000</option>
                <option <?php if ($max == '6000000'){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> value="6000000">&#163;6,000,000+</option>
              </select>
          </dd>
          <dt>Regions</dt><dd><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" /></dd>

          <dt><input <?php if( $area1 == '43' ){ echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> type="checkbox" name="cou1" id="couHertfordshire" value="43" /></dt><dd>Hertfordshire</dd>
          <dt><input <?php if( $area2 == '126' ){ echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> type="checkbox" name="cou2" id="couLondonNorth" value="126" /></dt><dd>London, North</dd>
          <dt><input <?php if( $area3 == '127' ){ echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> type="checkbox" name="cou3" id="couLondonNorthWest" value="127" /></dt><dd>London, North West</dd>

            <input type="hidden" name="cou" id="couHertfordshire_hide" value="<?php if ( $area1 == '43' ) { echo '43';} ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="cou" id="couLondonNorth_hide" value="<?php if ( $area2 == '126' ) { echo '126';} ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="cou" id="couLondonNorthWest_hide" value="<?php if ( $area3 == '127' ) { echo '127';} ?>" />

            <input type="hidden" name="slo" value="undefined" />
            <input type="hidden" name="fid" value="894" />
            <input type="hidden" name="bid" value="0" />
            <input type="hidden" name="dbt" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="nre" value="undefined" />
            <input type="hidden" name="thu" value="undefined" />
            <input type="hidden" name="vto" value="undefined" />
            <input type="hidden" name="ord" value="undefined"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="nba" value="undefined" />

          <dt><input type="submit" class="search_now" value="Find Property" /></dt><dd><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" /></dd>
        </dl>
      </form>

      <?php if($js_submit){ ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                document.forms["searchform"].submit();
            });
        </script>

        <?php } ?>

      <div><a href="register.php" class="register_with_us"><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" /></a></div>
      <div><a href="contact.php" class="our_branches"><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" /></a></div>
      <div><a href="valuation.php" class="free_valuation"><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" /></a></div>

        <?php
        if ($page!='getvaluation')
       { ?> 
       <h1 class='bot_line'>Featured <span>Property</span></h1>
      <div>
      <?php perch_content('Featured Property Image');?>           
      </div>
      <h3><?php perch_content('Featured Property Title'); ?></h3>
     <p>
     <?php perch_content('Featured Property Description'); ?>

     </p>      
     <?php }  ?>
    </div>
     <div>

  </div>
```

**Code for Valuation Page**

```
<?php 
$page='getvaluation'; 
include('perch/runtime.php'); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1    /DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang='en' dir='ltr'>
<head>
<title>Squires Estates - Independent Estate Agent, London</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<link href="css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!--[if IE]>
<![if lt IE 7]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/DD_belatedPNG.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ie6.js"></script>
<![endif]>
<![endif]-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="slider/themes/default/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="slider/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="slider/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slider/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        controlNav: false,
        effect: 'fade', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
    });
});
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
 function blurInspection(el, text) {if (el.value == '') {el.value=text;}}
 function focusInspection(el, text) {if (el.value == text) {el.value='';}}
</script>

</head>

<body>


<div id="wrapper">

<?php include("header.php"); ?>

  <div id="content">
    <div class="left_part left_home">
      <h1 class="bot_line">Please use the form below to arrange a free valuation</span></h1>
      <?php 
      // Text Section
      //perch_content('form');?>
      <?php perch_content('Form Text');?>
    </div>
    <?php 
    include('sidebar.php');
    include('footer.php');
    ?>
```

Comment: Does $page='results'; come before the sidebar include?

Comment: $page='results'; is at the very top of the page. include('sidebar.php'); is near the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're including the file that assigns `result` to `$page` before you do the comparing.

So,

This is bad:

```
<?php
if ($page!='results')
{?>
<h1>THE MAIN SIDEBAR CONTENT</h1>
<div>
SOME CONTENT          
</div>
<?php }  
include("the-file-here-that-defines-$page");//The include line is AFTER the comparing here...which means the $page value will not be changed until after the comparing...
?>
```

This is good:

```
<?php
include("the-file-here-that-defines-$page");//the include line is BEFORE the comparing, so $page will change before, and it should all work well..
if ($page!='results')
{?>
<h1>THE MAIN SIDEBAR CONTENT</h1>
<div>
SOME CONTENT          
</div>
<?php }  

?>
```

EDIT:

I've taken a look at your edit, and my original suggestion is causing the issue. In your `sidebar.php` you have `$page = explode('/', $page);` which is executed **after** you do `$page='getvaluation';` but, you're also doing your comparing in `sidebar.php` which you also re-define `$page` in.

A quick fix for this would be to simply use another variable to represent 'getvaluation':

So, in your sidebar.php:

```
if($getValuation===true){$page='getvaluation';}//check if $getValuation is true (which will will be defined in your valuation page)
        if ($page!='getvaluation')
       { ?> 
       <h1 class='bot_line'>Featured <span>Property</span></h1>
      <div>
      <?php perch_content('Featured Property Image');?>           
      </div>
      <h3><?php perch_content('Featured Property Title'); ?></h3>
     <p>
     <?php perch_content('Featured Property Description'); ?>

     </p>      
     <?php }  ?>
    </div>
     <div>
```

And now, in your valuation page:

Instead of:

```
<?php 
$page='getvaluation';
```

do this:

```
<?php 
$getValuation=true;
```

and on other pages (pages where you would like the side bar to show), simply do not define `$getValuation` or assign it to `false`:

Comment: thanks, I still can't get that to work, it just doesn't seem to recognise that the page has $page!='results'

Comment: have you tried echoing `$page`? if not try doing `echo '<br>page currently is: '.$page."<br>";` **inside the if statement**. And tell me what the response is.

Comment: If I do that it says  'page currently is: Array'

Comment: So that means you're defining `$page` somewhere as an array...post all of your code (including the code in your included file) in your question.

Comment: No problem Andrew. It's really not that hard to understand. PHP code is always executed line by line, so the line at the top of the page will be executed before the line at the bottom of the page (or any other line below the one at the top). And, when you include file in a script, the line you have `include()` on is where that other files code will sit. Understand that, and you're pretty much sorted. Happy coding xD